# ZBarReader QR Code detection time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, zbar-sdk

In my app i'm using `ZBarReader`, and i can able to detect the `QRCode` and `BarCode` using the code

```
ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
reader.readerDelegate = self;
reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
// TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

// EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
[scanner setSymbology:0 config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:0];
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_QRCODE
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 1];

reader.tracksSymbols=YES;
reader.readerView.zoom=1.0;


// present and release the controller
[self presentModalViewController: reader
                        animated: YES];
[reader release];
```

But it detects the code only **when i make my camera much closer to the barcode, it's not detecting when i keep my camera little far from barcode** Is there any property to scan the code very Quickly even when i have camera far from barcode..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Zbar reader depends on the camera resolution of the device but still try using

```
reader.readerView.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720;
```

adjust  `AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720` .May this helps.

Comment: it says use of undeclared identifier AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720.

Comment: add the AVFoundation.framework in your project and include it in your class.

Comment: this works without the error you might be missing something else.

Comment: i told you in the beginning only that the Zbar reader majorly depends on the resolution of the camera of device you are using ... ipad has 1 MegaPixel or 2 MegaPixel camera which is low ... if you will try same with an iPhone this will work just fine.